# E-mail on expiration date PHP

Tags: php, linux

I have an application where users enter data that has an expiration date. I need to e-mail the users who entered that data when the expiration date arrives. I read about cron jobs, but I'm not sure if it's the optimal solution here. How do I go about this please? My hosting company is hostgator and they use Linux servers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Program a cron for example in PHP that every day check if is the expiration date for any user in your database and send an email to these users is the solution.

You need to have access to server with console, command to modify crons is: crontab -e

Is easy to find info about how to program a crontab. Try and ask if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

write an SQL query which gives you the expiration date.

For loop the each user on that expiration date.
eg.make this in `auto_mail_on_expiry.php`

Make that php file in the cron job that executes every day at particular time, if the sql query has values it will mail it or else nothing goes.

If you need, give the db and I will write the php and crontab.